# How can i prevent Symfony ADMIN_ROLE to impersonate an SUPER_ADMIN_ROLE?

Tags: symfony, impersonation

The problem is...

I configured the ADMIN_ROLE to impersonate ANY user.
But i have an SUPER_AMIN_ROLE where i can add new ADMIN, and change some vital application things.

How can i prevent those ADMIN_ROLE to impersonate my account?

I was stopped at this point....

Here is my security.yml file:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Cliente: bcrypt
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
              class: AppBundle:Cliente
              property: cpf

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
              login_path: login
              check_path: login
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login
                invalidate_session: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   ~damMe~HIDDED
                lifetime: ~damMe~HIDDED
                path:     /dashboard
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/cadastro, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
        - { path: ^/cliente, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, USER_ROLE ] }
        - { path: ^/indicados, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, USER_ROLE ] }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_REGIONAL, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you may or you may not, there's no logic behind impersonation.

What you can do, is implement an event listener to listen to `security.switch_user`. You have the target user in there. You don't know the actual roles assigned by the hierarchy of that person so you will have to find another way to determine if they may or may not. Personally I'm not a fan of the hierarchy as ROLES are used to identify and not authorize.

In this event you could throw an exception, but I'm not sure how effective this will be on sequential requests.

Please check out [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html#events) about the event. [Here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.1/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Event/SwitchUserEvent.php) you can see what the event contains.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution but works for me

```
class SwitchUserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onSwitchUser(SwitchUserEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();         
        if ($request->hasSession() && $event->getRequest()->getRequestUri() !== '/?_switch_user=_exit') {
            if (SecurityHelper::isUserAdmin($event->getTargetUser())) {
                throw new LogicException('Forbidden to impersonate Administrator!!!');
            }
        }
    }     

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::SWITCH_USER => 'onSwitchUser',
        ];
    }
}
```